# insert value from one table into another whilst doing a double insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

Not sure that this is even possible.  I am inserting values into two tables at the same time using multi_query.  That works fine.  One of the tables has an auto increment column and I need to take the last auto incremented number and insert it into the second table so like this: insert into table 1 then take the last inserted number from column X and insert it along with other data into table 2.  I have played around with using SELECT LAST and INSERT INTO but so far its just doing my head in.  The insert statements looks like this:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO tbleClients (riskClientId, riskFacility, riskAudDate)     VALUES ('$riskclient2', '$facility2', '$riskdate2');";

$sql .="SELECT     LAST(riskId) FROM tbleClients;";$sql .="INSERT INTO tblRiskRegister (riskId)     SELECT riskId FROM tbleClients ;";

$sql .= "INSERT INTO tblRiskRegister     (riskAudDate, riskClientId,       riskSessionId, RiskNewId) VALUES     ('$riskdate2', '$riskclient2', '$sessionid', '$risknewid')";
```

Individually they all produce results but I need it to happen simultaneously. I did toy with the idea of doing them all separately but figure thats not very efficient. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I actually looked at that the other day for multi query problem and it solved it but I never noticed the last insert id part.  Now that answer had killed two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO tbleClients (riskClientId, riskFacility, riskAudDate)     VALUES ('$riskclient2', '$facility2', '$riskdate2');";
```

After executing the above query, using mysqli_insert_id(), which gives you the last insert id.

So below query is useless.
$sql .="SELECT     LAST(riskId) FROM tbleClients;";

```
$sql .="INSERT INTO tblRiskRegister (riskId)     SELECT riskId FROM tbleClients ;";
```

You can insert last_insert_id in above query.

Unable to find the relation between above & below query.

```
$sql .= "INSERT INTO tblRiskRegister     (riskAudDate, riskClientId,       riskSessionId, RiskNewId) VALUES     ('$riskdate2', '$riskclient2', '$sessionid', '$risknewid')";
```

Comment: which is what I ended up doing.  Thank you.